# Data connection to SQL SMS when loading table to Power Query - Data compression

Tags: sql, compression, powerpivot

I would like to load a database from SQL Server Management Studio to a Power Pivot but I see in my SQL SMS that the size of the table is :

[image]

And when I load it it changes to 135,6 MB. I think it is because I see it creates a connection between SQL SMS and the Power Pivot:

[image]

If that is the case, is there any way of deleting the connection? Or maybe it is another reason for the size to get bigger?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 135,6 MB > 1'525.688 MB?

Comment: As Alexis pointed, your data was compressed more than 10x after it was copied to power pivot. If you want to avoid copying data from sql server to power pivot, you need to use SQL Server Analytical Services/Tabular. Or instead of Power Pivot use Power BI in Direct Query Mode. (Both require advanced skills).